# Cron job runs, however doesn't log to file and doesn't output data to .csv

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cron

I have used a cloud scheduler function to spin up my instance two minutes before I run a cron job. I have a cron job that runs a scraper, I can see on syslog that the cron command fires.

```
Nov 15 21:50:01 saying-i CRON[1260]: (franticoreo) CMD (/home/franticoreo/saying/perth_geo_search_tweets.py &>> /home/franticoreo/saying/test.log)
```

This python program writes a .csv when it has finished scraping from the twitter api.

I have ran the cron command when I have been active on the terminal and it outputs the log file and writes the csv. However, it seems that it doesn't write the log file or output the data when it is running by itself. My scraper runs for six cycles and then stops, the expected CPU/Network behaviour on the 'Monitor VM's' tab is reflected in the plots.

Comment: I'm not following the story.  Are you spinning up a GCP Compute Engine and then running a Python app in that Compute Engine where the app is started by local CRON?   How/where does Cloud Scheduler come into the picture?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Cloud Scheduler to run a Compute Engine, which runs a Python webscraper. When I spin up the instance manually, I get input. When the VM gets spun up by Cloud Scheduler, it runs but there is no output (no log file, no .csv output).

Comment: When I look at Cloud Scheduler (https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating) I see that it either publishes a message to PubSub or sends an HTTP request.  What are you using?  How does this start a Compute Engine instance?

Comment: That's right, I followed an official tutorial from [here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule). From the tutorial "This tutorial shows how to use Cloud Scheduler and Cloud Functions to automatically start and stop Compute Engine instances on a regular schedule using resource labels. "

Comment: Hi @franticoreo , so I replicated your use case but didn't have any issue actually. it could be that you are shutting down the instance before your job is finishing running. if you ssh to your running instance, will you be able to see the result of your cron job?